# How to Change Line-Height Element in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Custom CSS is causing any change in making the nav elements center with respect to the height of the navbar. Please Click on this text to [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtlh0.png)

**Custom CSS** [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb1RJ.png)

Comment: Can add some code snippet?

Comment: i attached the image to the text. just click buddy. Thanks

Comment: have you tried adding 'px' to your line-height?

Comment: Yes @iamjhu but not effect still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just add `!important` beside your `line-height` number

example

```
.blabla {
    line-height:70px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Habib. That worked! However i had to reduce the pixel to half the original height to center it. Thanks once again

Comment: Ok. nope, you can click tick button left my answer. so other user know the right answer